# Beagleboard SNES with non-Tomee controller?

Tags: emulation

Anyone here know anything about using non-Tomee controllers with BeagleSNES? The guide says there is only official support for Tomee, I was wondering if there was any unofficial.

Comment: Just depends on the signaling on the interconnect, but if you're programatically inclined I'm sure you can get the code modified.  Their entire code stack is OSS so get in there and learn, that's what the BeagleBoard is really for.

Answer (score -1):

> The only supported game controller is the Tomee USB SNES gamepad, **though most USB gamepads with enough buttons will work if you tweak the BeagleSNES code to support their button mapping**.

This could be through the SNES9x emulator that's running or through some lower level code, but I'm not going to do the legwork of digging through the compiled files to find it.  As they say in my math text books, "This is an exercise left to the reader."

Comment: Downvote with no comment?  You stay class San Diego.